# export data to xml by the use of query to xml then importing it using xpath

Tags: postgresql, xml

i have use QUERY_TO_XML function in order to export data to xml , after that i want to export this data. this data might contain reserved chars in the xml tags like "' & ..."
ex  electrical ' engineer.
i am using xpath to extract the data into temp table then inserting this data to the receiving table by the use of the temp table.
what to do in order to escape this charcater while using xpath.